# How to save flow of questions/answers that are dependent on previous answers?

Tags: php, sql, database, oracle

I am making an application where I have to ask questions and depending on answers given, I have to ask other questions until the end of the process.

Example: Next question depends on A1

Scenario 1:

Q1: Are you married ? Y / N

A1: Y

Q2: Enter the date of marriage?
...

Scenario 2:

A1: N

Q2: Do you intend to get married? Y/N

A2: Y

Q3: In which country you like to get married? 1.USA 2.Canada 3.Others
...

End scenarios

Questions can be simple Yes/No, input value, Selection from multiple choices

How do I save these in a database together with the flow control of questions and answers?

Comment: Do you have the CMS do add question and answer in DB or these are fixed static questions?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727608/for-an-online-questionnaire-how-to-design-a-database-for-keeping-track-of-all-u) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270776/can-you-recommend-a-database-design-for-quiz-questions-and-answers-that-would-al)

Comment: Questions and answers will be saved in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a CMS backend to add questions and answers, the approach I would suggest as per my experience of working on such functionality is

1. Creat to tables in DB, eg. 
   `primary_questions` and `sub_questions`
2. Create 1:M relationship with the tables; `primary_questions` HAS MANY `sub_questions`. Maintain the `primary_que_id` as foreign key
3. In your CMS while adding questions, add an action/button to add a subquery to the primary question.
4. On submit, check if POST has subquery added. If Yes, insert the main question in `primary_questions` table and then in response to the same insert, Insert into `sub_questions` table. You will get foreign key `primary_que_id` by insert query of primary question.

Footnote: 
[To get the last inserted ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558979/inserting-into-oracle-and-retrieving-the-generated-sequence-id)
[Exaple Queries](http://psoug.org/reference/sequences.html)

Hope this helps!